# Staircasing resident memory usage in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory, memory-leaks

In one of our apps, we're finding that when usage spikes, RSS (as reported by `top(1)` for example) increases, hits a plateau and starts oscillating, but never comes back down.  After a bit of a break, stressing the server again results in another higher plateau.  This trend continues into the many gigabytes of RAM.

At first we suspected a memory leak on the Javascript side, and so started tracking the statistics returned by `process.memoryUsage()`:

[image: Observed Trends in RSS, Heap Total, and Heap Used]

A few phases here:

- After starting the server, we hit it with 100 concurrent long running requests for a few minutes and then left the server running for the evening.  RSS stayed at around 320MB for the night; and heap usage just kept oscillating.  We were emitting traces every minute so maybe this explained the movement in the heap.
- At around 9a, we hit it with another round of concurrent requests and transitioned to a workflow involving 2 threads of rolling long running requests (downloads of 10MB of data).  We kept these running until around 2p and stopped them.  During this phase, after the initial bump in RSS, it again started to level off and stay between around 400 and 450MB.
- The last bit is another round of concurrent requests.  Here, RSS grew to between 480MB and 500MB

I'm wondering if there are ways to figure out what's going on outside the heap that could be consuming all of this memory and not releasing it.  Short of that, are there any hidden options for limiting memory usage outside of the heap?

And I have to ask.  Are we making too much of this?  Is this about normal for Node?